# bootsfaces dataTable change default values

Tags: jsf, datatable, localization, bootsfaces

How to change the value of the labels on the following cases:

- Show  N entries
- Search
- Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries
- Previous Next

These fields are generated just by using the  `<b:dataTable>`

I would like to give them different names, even for internationalization use different language.

By looking at http://www.bootsfaces.net/forms/DataTable.jsf I see nothing explaining how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the Locale and Language of the Bootfaces DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181373/change-the-locale-and-language-of-the-bootfaces-datatable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTable widget of BootsFaces 0.8.x is still in its infancy. Currently, we're working hard to bring you all the features you need - internationalization and renaming labels included. Maybe you want to watch the discussion on our bug tracker (https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/301).

By the way, it's surprisingly simple to replace the BootsFaces dataTable by standard JSF 2.x code and a few lines of JavaScript. The example below uses one of the standard I18n files to translate the labels to Spanish. You can easily adapt the code to support your language or your custom labels.

```
<h:dataTable value="{{carPool.carPool}}" var="car" id="carPool" styleClass="table table-striped table-bordered"
  style="width:100%">
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Brand" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Type" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:inputText value="#{car.type}" />
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#carPool').DataTable({
   "language": {
       "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.10/i18n/Spanish.json"
   }
 });
} );
</script>
```

I did this in the most examples of http://www.bootsfaces.net/forms/DataTable.jsf. You'll find the source code here: [pure HTML](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFacesWeb/blob/master/src/main/webapp/forms/dataTable.html) and [JSF 2.x](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFacesWeb/blob/master/src/main/webapp/forms/DataTable.xhtml). As a third alternative, you can construct the HTML code using ui:repeat.